# Find a text in a bitmap image

Tags: bitmap, ocr

I need to determine if a set of string is displayed in a set of images.

This is a simplified OCR case with these simplifications :

- **Fixed** font family and size
- Images are **bitmaps** (gif, png).
- **No antialiasing**
- I only need a **true/false result**, not necessarily a position index.

The main difficulties are performance. I need to test hundreds of terms in thousands of pictures.

I need pointers for algo, languages, ...

Thank you.